# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'tanh'

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to repeat what is shown in this tutorial: https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/deep-reinforcement-learning

When I run this code:

```
# Check version of tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

I am getting this error:

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '**version**'

When I run this piece of code I am not getting any error:

```
from kaggle_environments import make, evaluate
from gym import spaces

class ConnectFourGym:
...
```

Then running this code without error:

```
# Create ConnectFour environment
env = ConnectFourGym(agent2="random")
```

But when I try to run the following code

```
import os
from stable_baselines.bench import Monitor 
from stable_baselines.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

# Create directory for logging training information
log_dir = "ppo/"
os.makedirs(log_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Logging progress
monitor_env = Monitor(env, log_dir, allow_early_resets=True)

# Create a vectorized environment
vec_env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: monitor_env])
```

I am getting the following error:

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'tanh'

The error is pointing these lines causing the problem:

```
----> 2 from stable_baselines.bench import Monitor 
...
----> 1 from stable_baselines.a2c import A2C 
...
----> 1 from stable_baselines.a2c.a2c import A2C 
...
----> 9 from stable_baselines.common import explained_variance, tf_util, ActorCriticRLModel, SetVerbosity, TensorboardWriter 
...
----> 7 from stable_baselines.common.base_class import BaseRLModel, ActorCriticRLModel, OffPolicyRLModel, SetVerbosity, 
...
---> 16 from stable_baselines.common.policies import get_policy_from_name, ActorCriticPolicy     ...
--> 375 class LstmPolicy(RecurrentActorCriticPolicy):
```

Why this is happening? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by specifying TensorFlow version:

```
# Check version of tensorflow
!pip install -q 'tensorflow==1.15.0'
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

This code snippet installs TensorFlow version 1.15.0 and prints

> '1.15.0'